# Why does the speaker not attribute to ALL sources?

Tags: names, masecheth-avodah-zarah, chinuch-education

On 16b of Masechet Avodah Zarah, the gemara recounts a situation in which R' Zeira tells of a fact he learned from R' Yehudah. R' Yehudah learned it from someone important but doesn't recall if it was Rav or Shmu'el.

R' Zeira then explains that he was later in Kurkunia, he heard R' Chiya bar Ashi recount the same teaching in the name of Shmu'el. Later, in Sura, R' Zeira encounters Rabbah bar Yirmiyah who recites the same teaching in the name of Rav. R' Zeira decides that the ruling is in both their names.

When the gemara codifies the statement it relates that what is stated is "R' Zeira said in the name of Rav Assi, who said in the name of Rabbah bar Yirmiyah, who said in the name of R' Chama bar Guria who said in the name of Rav..." but there is no mention at all of Shmu'el.

Why, if this was (at least) also said by Shmu'el, as related via R' Chiya Bar Ashi, does the summary completely delete any reference to R' Chiya bar Ashi and Shmu'el? If there is merit in stating something in the name of the one who said it, and the gemara lists 4 names, tracing it to Rav, why isn't also proper to include any chain of teaching that connects it to Shmu'el?

Comment: Probably because Rav is more authoritative than Shmuel in non-monetary matters.

Comment: maybe because the gemara is relying on the story it brought earlier, for the reader to know it was also in the name of shmuel

Comment: @Yaakov5777 the same story also said it was in the name of Rav. But when it recaps, it retells the Rav part and ignores the Shmuel part.

Comment: @rosends maybe it had to pick at least one, but didnt want to write more than it has to

Comment: @Yaakov5777 if reporting something b'shem omro is an important value, then it is more important than not wanting to write a few extra words.

Comment: @rosends in the gemara every word is exact, in this case it went out of its way to tell stories about the shem omro, if its possible to not have to write any extra words, it makes sense for it to only say the bare minimum

Comment: @Yaakov5777 but omitting a name then undercuts the power of the shem omro argument. If there is a reason to omit, then what is it?

Comment: @rosends the reason is probably because it has to omit one of them in order not to write extra words, maybe it chose rav over shmuel because of what nt said

Comment: @Yaakov5777 but they both made the exact same ruling. Why would any claim that one is more authoritative have any bearing?

Comment: @rosends i told u my guess, without seeing the commentaries i cant say for sure, but i do know the language of the gemara in general is very concise, like it says in pesachim that one should always teach in "derech katzara"--a short way [if its still understood etc]